# Vim - 256 colors enabled, only 16 work

Tags: vim, colors, zsh, 256color

I can't modify my Vim colors using the 256 colors grid (http://www.calmar.ws/vim/256-xterm-24bit-rgb-color-chart.html).
Unfortunately, only the 16 basic colors work. Colors from the 256 colors grid are replaced by an equivalent in the 16 colors grid: color 88 will become color 1, 214 will become 11, 224 will become 15, etc.

Here is what I use in my **~/.vimrc** concerning colors:

```
set t_Co=256
highlight comment ctermfg=grey
highlight constant ctermfg=224
syntax enable
```

With this code, comments are grey and constants are white (whereas they should be beige).

I thought it would be of use to let you know that when I typed `tput colors` in my shell, the result was "256", which means (if I am not mistaken) that 256 colors are enabled. When I typed `echo $TERM`, the result was "xterm-256color", and if I am not mistaken (again), this means that I have correctly installed a 256-colors plugin.

It may be useful for you to know that I use **zsh**.

I ran some scripts to show the supported colors of my terminal, here is the result:
[image]

I don't understand why I can't use the 256 colors package. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Your terminal emulator also needs to be able to handle this, after all, it is the thing displaying the colors to you. Which one are you using, and on what platform?

Comment: Check out if your terminal really support 256 colors: `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alghanmi/terminal_color_test/master/256colors2.pl | perl`. After "Color cube, 6x6x6" must be all 256 colors showed

Comment: @komar it seems like it actually does not: http://zupimages.net/up/17/16/i1ed.png

Comment: @DanLowe I use zsh, with oh-my-zsh, on bash. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: It looks like 256 color on Windows 10 just isn't supported. But a program called mintty may be able to do this. See https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/76